# Pick up and read the code in RGB hum mouseDown event in C #

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I want every time I click somewhere ( either in the form or a picture, des that has color) that has color, read and "capture" / " store " the RGB value of that location.

And as the first time I've been trying to do something , I even lost in what to use or not to use and really I'm on the right track :

Current state:

```
private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Point p = e.Location;
        label1.Text = Convert.ToString(p);
        label1.Refresh();

        int x, y;
        System.Drawing.Color cor = new Bitmap(" ").GetPixel(x, y);
        MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(cor.R) + Convert.ToString(cor.G) + Convert.ToString(cor.B));
    }
```

After searching for something that could be necessary, falls into the " GetPixel " but do not know if it really served to what I want , because until then as I said, the first time I try something related .

Two problems :

- Do not know how I will use the "x " and " y" to get the position , although I can get the two only with the " Point p = e.Location ; " but I can not use it with the GetPixel .
- How will not be necessarily every time I open an image to check and will not be the same or may be I just want to know the color within a form.

I shall be grateful if someone could help me find the right one , do not want the answer.

Comment: A `Point` has `X` and `Y` properties. What is `new Bitmap(" ")` supposed to do? What pixel are you trying to get? Something you're displaying on your form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite complicated for each of these scenarios will have to be handled differently. For the form, does it have a constant background colour or is it variable?

But for the picture box you would need to assign a `picturebox mouse click event` to it, much in a similar way to how you've done it for the form. Now once you've done that you need to work out where on the picture box it was clicked. You've already done this i.e. `e.Location`. From there it is simply getting the pixel at that location:

```
Color color = pictureBoxControl.Image.GetPixel(e.Location.X, e.Location.Y);
```

Note that depending on your image you might also have to check the position in the `PictureBox` that was clicked is on the picture i.e. was it on the picture or the margin. If it's in the margin your color is simply the `BackgroundImage` or `BackgroundColor` property. This can then be applied to other controls and also the form.

Also `GetPixel` is really slow and you may want to have a look at `Bitmap.LockBits`.

Comment: Made by all examples given here, but his was the simplest, however had trouble running because the error in the "GetPixel".

Comment: I'm free to help if you comment on what the error is... Also note that @MarcWittmann's answer is more correct than mine and possibly what you want to add in

Comment: ok, I will explain the error and will exchange an idea with you, great!

Comment: I did as you introduced me, I put a through image picturebox and say that my variable "color" has the value of my photo, so that it becomes possible to be accessed by color class, just put the end of the code the "GetPixel "beeps a mistake like that.

Other examples worked out, put your e through a photo placed on the form and it becomes more interesting to me if you can help me, but I'll try here.

Comment: `private void Form1_Load (object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile ("E:\\dowload\\forest-noite.jpg");
             pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;

         }

private void pictureBox1_MouseDown (object sender, and MouseEventArgs)
         {
             Point p = e.Location;
             Color color = pictureBox1.Image.GetPixel (e.Location.X, e.Location.Y);
             MessageBox.Show (Convert.ToString (color));
         }`

Comment: @GuilhermeMarcial you need to offset for the location of the picturebox

Answer (score 1):

Accoring to the example code of "GetPixel" you can just use the

`Cursor.Position.X` `Cursor.Position.Y` here (see second line of full example below)
so just use:

```
 GetPixel(hdc, p.X, p.Y);
```

full example:

```
 static private void myControl_MouseMove(object sender,System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
 {
   IntPtr hdc = GetDC(IntPtr.Zero); 
   uint pixel = GetPixel(hdc, Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y);
   ReleaseDC(IntPtr.Zero,hdc);
   Color color = Color.FromArgb((int)pixel);
   Console.WriteLine("Color is {0}",color);
 }
```

The rest of the functions are just imported gdi/user32 libraries

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetDC(IntPtr hwnd);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern Int32 ReleaseDC(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr hdc);

[DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
static extern uint GetPixel(IntPtr hdc,int nXPos,int nYPos);
```

Should work like a charm.

Further explanation:

- The GetDC function retrieves a handle to a device context (DC) for the client area of a specified window or for the entire screen. You can also use the returned handle in subsequent GDI functions to draw in the DC.
- Release DC releases the handle.
- The color has to be converted from Argb to Rgp
- The GetPixel function  [detailed information here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/dd144909%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) retrieves the red, green, blue color value of the pixel at the specified coordinates with

  - A handle to the device context.
  - The x-coordinate, in logical units, of the pixel to be examined.
  - The y-coordinate, in logical units, of the pixel to be examined.

Comment: This is obviously more correct than my answer, but would you mind explaining it a bit more instead of just being code only

Comment: You´re right, tried to basically explain the functions

Comment: Thank you, I will study up and move on to the second part of that and create a table of codes "RGB" to compare and inform color to the User.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to create a screenshot of your window:

```
    private System.Drawing.Bitmap TakeScreenshot()
    {
        int StartX, StartY;
        int Width, Height;

        StartX = 0;
        StartY = 0;
        Width = Convert.ToInt32(this.Width);
        Height = Convert.ToInt32(this.Height);

        System.Drawing.Bitmap Screenshot = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(Width, Height);
        System.Drawing.Graphics G = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(Screenshot);

        G.CopyFromScreen(StartX, StartY, 0, 0, new System.Drawing.Size(Width, Height));
        G.Dispose();
        return Screenshot;
    }
```

Then you need your mouse position:

```
    Point current = e.Location;
```

And your color is:

```
    Bitmap colorpicker = TakeScreenshot();
    Point current = e.Location;
    hoverColor = colorpicker.GetPixel(current.X,current.Y);
    colorpicker.Dispose();
```

The created bitmap includes all pixel and their color of your window and with the current mouse position you have the x-coordinate and the y-coordinate you choose the pixel you want to get from the bitmap and by calling the method GetPixel you get the color of your pixel.

Comment: I like the approach, but again same thing as I said to Marc, would you mind explaining the code a bit instead of just dumping it all here and secondly note that you aren't wrapping the graphics object in an using statement so it won't be disposed of and could cause memory leaks and the same for the screenshot bitmap (obviously when you've finished using it)

Comment: Thank you for assistance, will be of good use to the project.